# Should you find + verb with -ing or present?

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive

I have been thinking about how to phrase this and it is getting me confused. I am trying to suggest that an item can be a great tool for a project. I'm using the idiom "Should you find" but I don't know what tense of the verb to use afterwards. Could you tell me which of these 4 options is/are correct (or maybe none)?

> Should you find this item suiting your project

> Should you find this item suit your project (infinitive)

> Should you find this item suits your project

> Should you find that this item suits your project

Comment: The relativizer "that" is completely optional and it makes absolutely no difference whether you include it or not. We don't have any context here (just *part* of a sentence), but offhand I can't easily think of a context where the continuous verb form *(**suiting**)* would be preferred. And personally, I think *whatever* the full context, it would be better to use ***if*** rather than ***should*** [like nearly everyone else](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+you+find+this%2CShould+you+find+this%2CIf+you+should+find+this&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: Following the edit, your first version is non-idiomatic, the second is ungrammatical, and the other two are both equally acceptable (and equivalent).

Comment: FF. I don't understand why you talk of the relativiser "that". There's no relative clause present.

Comment: It's apparently an attempt to sound like a bespoke tailor. That explains the _should_, which falutes higher than _if_. If you're determined to use _find_ without a complementizer to mark the clause (including one is a good idea), you can't use a gerund, so (1) is out. The infinitive is OK, but needs a _to_. The last two are fine. Everything is governed by the matrix verb (_find_), and the presence or absence of a raised subject (in this case _this item_).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149010/discussion-on-question-by-vince-should-you-find-verb-with-ing-or-present); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fumblefingers answered in a comment:

> The relativizer "that" is completely optional and it makes absolutely no difference whether you include it or not. We don't have any context here (just *part* of a sentence), but offhand I can't easily think of a context where the continuous verb form *(**suiting**)* would be preferred. And personally, I think *whatever* the full context, it would be better to use ***if*** rather than ***should*** [like nearly everyone else](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+you+find+this%2CShould+you+find+this%2CIf+you+should+find+this&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

And also:

> Following the edit, your first version is non-idiomatic, the second is ungrammatical, and the other two are both equally acceptable (and equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

John Lawler answered in a comment:

> It's apparently an attempt to sound like a bespoke tailor. That explains the *should*, which falutes higher than *if*. If you're determined to use *find* without a complementizer to mark the clause (including one is a good idea), you can't use a gerund, so (1) is out. The infinitive is OK, but needs a *to*. The last two are fine. Everything is governed by the matrix verb (*find*), and the presence or absence of a raised subject (in this case *this item*).